# Typing 'ipconfig' into Command Prompt shows two IPv4 addresses. Which one is my computer?

Tags: windows-phone-8, ip-address, command-prompt, ipconfig

I'm tring to test my Windows Phone 8 app on an actual device, but I need the IP Address of my computer in order to do this. When I type 'ipconfig' in the command prompt, it shows two different IPv4 addresses and I can't tell which is the correct one for my computer that will allow me to test the app on a device.

Command Prompt Output:

```
Ethernet Adapter vEthernet <Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch>:
    IPv4 Address......: 169.254.xx.xx

Ethernet Adapter vEthernet <New Virtual Switch>:
    IPv4 Address......: 192.168.x.xxx
```

I'm having a heck of a time getting this app to actually work on a device so if there is anything you see that is off, by all means let me know. My concern in this question though, is which of these is the true IP Address of my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is your computer's IP address, the second one is for application or OS virtualization.

Answer (score 2):

The one starting with 169.254 you can safely ignore. If a device does not receive an IP from any DHCP server within a few seconds, it creates its own, starting with 169.254.x.x, but you can't reach anything with such an IP, nor can anything reach your device.

The second one is the real one in your case. 192.168.x.x means you are part of a private network (but it could also be 10.x.x.x).

Answer (score 2):

If you see multiple IPv4 addresses listed in command prompt as a result of `ipconfig` command, then the IPv4 address that has Default Gateway is your main or current device or computer IPv4 address.